# Do actions after promise is resolved in React

Tags: reactjs, promise

i have an api call in my react app,

```
function apicall(input) {
    return fetch(url)
    .then(response =>
        response.json())
}
```

This is called from another file

```
apicall(input).then(responseData => {
    //responseData is an array
    //some action->    responseData.map(
})
```

I felt this approach is not right, i just want the apicall to return data.
idea is something like this:
call  apicall
get the data
assign the response to variable 
loop the response (instead of doing it inside `then`)

Comment: for synchronously loading data, it's the right approach. callback eliminates the waiting and continues with the execution of next statements.

Answer (score 1):

when dealing with `Promise` you have to either use the `.then` syntax or the `async/await` way.

you can do something like this

```
    async function apicall(input) {
        return fetch(url)
        .then(response =>
            response.json())
    }


    // in some other file

    (async function(){ // enclosing function must be async
      const data = await apicall(input)
    })
```

Comment: `async` keyword should be before `function` keyword.

Answer (score 0):

You approach is correct just return data from correct place, and just need to use `async/await`,

```
async function apicall(input) {
    await fetch(url)
    .then(response =>
        response.json()
    )
    .then(response => {
        console.log(response);
        return response;
    })
}
```

And your `apicall` should be,

```
const returnData = apicall(input);
//do your operations on returnData here
```

Comment: here also, if i need to do operations on responseData,it has to be done inside then, what i would prefer is: const returnData;  apicall(input).then(responseData => {
    console.log(responseData);
returnData = responseData
}). After this call, do operation with returnData

Comment: @Parameswar No need to do as you prefer, I have updated answer have a look.

Comment: can this function return data instead of a promise ? function apicall(input) {
    return fetch(url)
    .then(response =>
        response.json())
}

Comment: as of now it returns a promise, if it returns data , then i dont need to use then

Comment: Have you tried my answer? I think it returns data only and a promise.

Comment: yup, i tried, but the data array is empty. the reason i think is, the promise is resolved after assigning to returnData. because i tried printing returnData, it gets printed first(empty) , and then the console.log you put is printed- which is proper data

Answer (score 0):

If you want to load your data synchronously, then it's the best approach.
otherwise, if you go with `async/wait` approach then your main thread will be blocked till you got a response. This (`async/wait`) approach is good if you want to create server-rendered pages. 
for `async/wait` approach follow @Prithwee Das's answer.